# ParametricPlot3D and Sphere Graphics

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, geometry

I'm trying to put a sphere into a 3D parametric plot, but I seem to have a strange problem. Here's the code:

```
(Gravitational Constant)
G = 6.672*10^-11
(Mass of Earth and rocket)
M = AstronomicalData["Earth", "Mass"]
m = 2800000
(Rocket thrust)
T = 34020000
(Radius of Earth)
r = AstronomicalData["Earth", "Radius"]
(Numerical solution modelling the gravitation interaction between Earth and a launching rocket)
(NOTE: Rocket mass will change over time; also, add in drag)
soln = NDSolve[{
   x''[t] == -((G M x[t])/(x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 + z[t]^2)^(3/2)),
   y''[t] == -((G M y[t])/(x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 + z[t]^2)^(3/2)) + 
     If[t > 1000, 0, 0.25 T/m],
   z''[t] == -((G M z[t])/(x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 + z[t]^2)^(3/2)) + 
     If[t > 1000, 0, 0.75 T/m],
   x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0, z[0] == r, x'[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, 
   z'[0] == 0}, {x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, 20000}, 
  MaxSteps -> 1000000, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"]
```

Show[ParametricPlot3D[
  Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. soln], {t, 0, 20000}, 
  AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, AspectRatio -> 1, BoxRatios -> 1, 
  PlotStyle -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large], 
 Graphics3D[{Green, Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, r]}]]

And this is the output that I get, not a sphere but a curved plane:

[image: Sphere Plot]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Everything is correct. It is part of sphere and with not so good parameters the orbit is inside the Earth :)

Comment: Please don't use `<pre><code>` and instead, indent by 4 spaces to format it as code. The former strips away the  the asterisks in the comments and they now appear as invalid code. I edited this in your previous question. Please edit the above in the same manner. Thanks :)

Comment: @rm-rf It's too localized or simple mistake I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show everything use `PlotRange->All` in `Show`. Without this it will take options from first argument which is `ParamatricPlot`.

Motion equation you are using assumes that Earth mass is focused in its center so the result might look strange since the orbit is inside for not efficient initial conditions:

```
Show[
     ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. soln], {t, 0, 20000},
                      AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, AspectRatio -> 1, BoxRatios -> 1, 
                      PlotStyle -> Thick, ImageSize -> Large],
     Graphics3D[{AbsolutePointSize@10, Red, Point[{0, 0, 0}], Green, 
                 Opacity@.1, Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, r]}]
     , PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 350]
```

[image]

Comment: Whoops hahaha, thanks again Kuba!